# python 3.6 centre tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.6

I have been using the below to centre a tkinter window with python 3.4.

```
root.eval('tk::PlaceWindow %s center' % root.winfo_pathname(root.winfo_id()))
```

This no longer works for me when using python 3.6 ?

What do I need to do, to make this work with python 3.6 ?

Comment: Are you just trying to place the tkinter root in the center of the monitor?

Comment: what does "no longer works" mean? Do you get an error? Does it place it in the wrong place?